# vectorizer.fit_transform gives NotImplementedError : adding a nonzero scalar to a sparse matrix is not supported

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn

I am trying to create a term document matrix using my custom analyser to extract features out of the documents. Following is the code for the same :

```
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(  \
                           ngram_range=(1,2),  
                        )
analyzer=vectorizer.build_analyzer()
def customAnalyzer(text):
    grams = analyzer(text)
    tgrams = [gram for gram in grams if not re.match("^[0-9\s]+$",gram)]
    return tgrams
```

This function is called to create the custom analyser, which is used by the countVectorizer to extract the features.

```
for i in xrange( 0, num_rows ):
    clean_query.append( review_to_words( inp["keyword"][i] , units))
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(analyzer = customAnalyzer,   \
                            tokenizer = None,    \
                            ngram_range=(1,2),  \
                            preprocessor = None, \
                            stop_words = None,   \
                            max_features = n,
                           )      
features = vectorizer.fit_transform(clean_query)
z = vectorizer.get_feature_names()
```

This call throws the following error:

```
(<type 'exceptions.NotImplementedError'>, 'python.py', 128,NotImplementedError('adding a nonzero scalar to a sparse matrix is not supported',))
```

This error comes when we call the vectorizer to fit and transform.
But the value of the variable clean_query is not scalar. I am using sklearn-0.17.1

```
 np.isscalar(clean_query)
 False
```

Comment: Post the data, so that we can duplicate the error.

Answer (score -1):

This is a small test which I did to reproduce the error, but it did not throw the same error for me. (This example has been taken from : [scikit-learn Feature extraction](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html))

`scikit-learn version : 0.19.dev0`

```
In [1]: corpus = [
   ...: ...     'This is the first document.',
   ...: ...     'This is the second second document.',
   ...: ...     'And the third one.',
   ...: ...     'Is this the first document?',
   ...: ... ]

In [2]: from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

In [3]: vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=1)

In [4]: vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
Out[4]: 
<4x9 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 19 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

In [5]: import numpy as np

In [6]: np.isscalar(corpus)
Out[6]: False

In [7]: type(corpus)
Out[7]: list
```

From the code above you can see, corpus is not a scalar and has the type list.

I think your solution lies in creating the `clean_query` variable, as expected by the `vectorizer.fit_transform` function.